# Missing initialized class variable

Tags: python

I wrote  some code to find the minimum number of events to count to 1 given any number n.

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        events=0
    def integerReplacement(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if n==1 or not n:
            return self.events
        if n%2==0:
            self.events=self.events+1
            self.integerReplacement(self,n/2)
        else:
            self.events=self.events+1
            self.integerReplacement(self,(n-1)/2)
        return self.events

def stringToInt(input):
    return int(input)

def intToString(input):
    if input is None:
        input = 0
    return str(input)

def main():
    import sys
    def readlines():
        for line in sys.stdin:
            yield line.strip('\n')
    lines = readlines()
    while True:
        try:
            line = lines.next()
            n = stringToInt(line)



                ret = Solution().integerReplacement(n)

                out = intToString(ret)
                print out
            except StopIteration:
                break

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The error i get is

```
Finished in N/A
AttributeError: 'Solution' object has no attribute 'events'
Line 12 in integerReplacement (Solution.py)
Line 38 in main (Solution.py)
Line 46 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I don't know why its not recognizing my events variable i am declaring in the init function. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `events=0` doesn't do anything, you will need to make it `self.events = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Cireo has commented, you need to use:

```
self.events = 0
```

self tells python that the variable declared has to be accessible to the entire class. Otherwise it's only accessible inside the local scope of the __init__ function. In other words, event and self.event would be two separate variables.

Alternatively, if you want to use events = 0 for whatever reason, you want to make it a class attribute, then your current code will work. To do that, remove your __init__ function and just declare the variable:

```
class Solution(object):
    event = 0

    # The rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be an attribute of the instance variable `self`, so change:

```
        events=0
```

To:

```
        self.events=0
```